# How can I find the list of instance types that do not require ENA and the list of AMIs that support ENA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-cli

I have this Terraform file -

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.23"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t3.nano"
}
```

When I run `terraform init && terraform apply` I get this error:

```
╷
│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Enhanced networking with the Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) is required for the 't3.nano' instance type. Ensure that you are using an AMI that is enabled for ENA.
│       status code: 400, request id: 1d85ba43-ffde-4840-9acb-8ac87c13fb24
│ 
│   with aws_instance.app_server,
│   on main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_instance" "app_server":
│   16: resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
│ 
╵
```

Two questions:

1. What AWS CLI command or what steps on [AWS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/) can I perform to find out the instance types that do not require ENA?
2. What AWS CLI command or what steps on [AWS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/) can I perform to find out the AMIs that support ENA?

Answer (score 0):

aws ec2 describe-instance-types --filters Name=network-info.ena-support,Values=supported,unsupported

may be more succinct to add --query 'InstanceTypes[].InstanceType'

You'll need to cross reference those with what is available in the region

aws ec2 describe-instance-type-offerings --location-type region --filters Name=location,Values=*region*